# Intercept disk activity on the level of physical blocks

Tags: windows, driver, low-level

I suppose this should be possible via filter driver, but what type exactly I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a class upper filter for volumes (Class=Volume, ClassGuid={71A27CDD-812A-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}) or disk drives (Class=DiskDrive, ClassGuid={4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}). Depending on at what level do you want to monitor physical blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I was under impression that this was the domain of the disk firmware. So you would have to work there.